# Was Claire Dearing blamed for any of Jurassic World's failings?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

**What happens to [Claire Dearing](http://www.jurassicworld.com/intel/character/claire-dearing), the operations manager, after the events in [Jurassic World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_World)?**

Just sitting watching it.

She dismisses the (very) unequivocal advice of one of her in-house experts to withdraw the capture team immediately on the grounds they'll all be killed.. following which, they all get killed.

Then dismisses his advice to immediately evacuate the entire park on the grounds the park would never reopen if she did.. and we all know how that ends, with an extravaganza of death & mayhem.

It seems highly implausible in any current real-world western legal system that she could escape any legal sanctions for her choices ~ multiple (hundreds isn't it?) cases of (extremely) negligent homicide if not outright murder charges seem inevitable.

*So is there any canon on her fate?*

Comment: http://www.jurassicworld.com/intel/character/claire-dearing

Comment: I'm assuming that in time-honoured tradition the company blamed it all on the dead guy and swept the rest under the carpet with lashings of cash to buy off the widows

Comment: You might also want to note that the whole thing took place in a country where the rule of law isn't what you'd describe as strong.

Comment: That sounds like a second related question "What legal framework does the island in Jurassic World come under" ~ I might ask it & link it after the film finishes if no one else has already.

Comment: I seem to recall from the original novel that Costa Rica was chosen specifically because they could buy off the goverment,

Comment: For an event as catastrophic & with as many deaths of people hailing from places like the US & Europe it seems unlikely they'd be able to buy off the government in the face of competing pressure from those other governments though ~ not without a cover up & media blackout that seems impossible to achieve given the number of foreign (not Venezuelan) customers.

Comment: God bless ambiguously vague release forms, that's all I can say.

Comment: ^ Oh _that's_ good! ~ lol

Answer (score 6):

The movie's [Official Novelisation](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/572702/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-the-junior-novelization-jurassic-world-fallen--kingdom-by-david-lewman-illustrated-by-random-house/9780525580768/) contains the rest of the conversation that we missed when Claire walked away from the camera during the establishing scenes at the start of the film.

In short, while it seems like she's (somewhat) blamed for what happened, she doesn't appear to have suffered any legal sanction for her actions on the island. Not only that, but even though people know who she is, they're still willing to entertain her calls and publicly support her organisation.

> *“Hi, Congresswoman Delgado. My name is Claire. I’m the lead organizer here,” said Claire as she moved around the room seeing to other matters while talking on the phone at the same time. She was a multitasking maven, applying corporate management skills for good.*
>
> *“Our mission at the Dinosaur Protection Group is to secure funds for a safe, natural habitat for these creatures,” said Claire, before stopping abruptly and listening to what was being said on the other end of the line.*
>
> ***She took a deep breath. “Yes. I am the same Claire Dearing who was the
> operations manager at Jurassic World. And yes, I do feel responsible
> for what happened there. That’s why I’m here doing what I’m doing
> now.”***

This tallies nicely with what we read in the film's [*Survival Guide*](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Jurassic_World:_Fallen_Kingdom_Survival_Guide), a factbook written from an in-universe perspective;

> **Claire Dearing**
>
> **Following the disaster at the park in 2015 she took some time off to decide what her next move would be.** Claire was disillusioned by the corporate world and no longer interested in working for a group driven solely by profit. She founded the Dinosaur Protection Group, a not-for-profit organization dedicated to saving the dinosaurs left stranded on Isla Nublar.

Comment: What! ~ No jail time? ~ Well that's buggered my suspension of disbelief then :)

Comment: @Pelinore - Everyone who died was undoubtedly in breach of the park's policies regarding interfering with the dinos.

Comment: @Valorum "Do not feed the animals"?

Comment: @PeterM - They were '[Making excessive noise](http://islanublar.jurassicworld.com/safety-first/)' with their screams.

Comment: @Pelinore: Exactly! _And yes, I do feel responsible for what happened there, **and all the people who died**. That is why I'm hell bent on raising enough money to buy enough nukes to sink the Island and destroy all traces of the dinosaurs._

Comment: @BinaryWorrier loved the first one but within a few years grew dissatisfied with the dinosaurs as I began to realize just how inaccurate they were (not just for how we _now_ think they looked but compared to consensus at the time in science "feathers & color dude"), I love the retcon explanation for that though (that is a retcon right?), helped restore my love, maybe future installments will have something for me here too :)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier ^ My feeling legal sanctions against her seems inevitable stems in the main from her decisions in the situation / command room contrary to expert advice in full view of multiple witnesses, perhaps none survived who would have been likely to blow the whistle.

Answer (score 4):

Unclear, but it does seem like the third movie will be about Claire and Owen's "Redemption".

> **EW**: Mills (Rafe Spall) tells Owen and Claire they’re the “parents” of this new age. Will the third film be them rectifying the wrongs and reversing Pandora’s box?
>
> **CT**: I don’t know if you can do that. But I do know that’s a very important scene. It very clearly identifies the narrative value of those two characters. It’s not just two people who happen to have been thrown together. The actions of those two individuals have really defined the story moving forward and the reason we’re there. **Their sense of responsibility is what this movie is about. The next movie is about their redemption.**
> <sub>*- [Jurassic World: Colin Trevorrow answers Fallen Kingdom burning questions - Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/movies/2018/06/22/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-burning-questions/)*</sub>

(Highlighting is mine) So, since he (Colin Trevorrow) throws around the term "Redemption" it is probably safe to assume that there were repercussions for Claire and Owen's actions.